# Reading NaN values from .csv files with decode_csv()

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I have .csv file with integer values, that can have NA value which represents missing data.

Example file:

```
-9882,-9585,-9179
-9883,-9587,NA
-9882,-9585,-9179
```

When trying to read it with

```
import tensorflow as tf

reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
key, value = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue, 1)
record_defaults = [[0], [0], [0]]
data, ABL_E, ABL_N = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
```

It throws following error later on `sess.run(_)` on the 2nd iteration

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Field 5 in record 32400 is not a valid int32: NA
```

Is there a way to interpret string "NA" while reading csv as NaN or similar value in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same problem. I solved it by reading the CSV as strings, replacing every occurrence of "NA" with some valid value, then converting it to float

```py
  # Set up reading from CSV files
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
  reader = tf.TextLineReader()
  key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  NUM_COLUMNS = XX # Specify number of expected columns

  # Read values as string, set "NA" for missing values.
  record_defaults = [[tf.cast("NA", tf.string)]] * NUM_COLUMNS 
  decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim="\t")
  # Replace every occurrence of "NA" with "-1"
  no_nan = tf.where(tf.equal(decoded,  "NA"), ["-1"]*NUM_COLUMNS, decoded)
  # Convert to float, combine to a single tensor with stack.
  float_row = tf.stack(tf.string_to_number(no_nan, tf.float32))
```

But long term I plan switching to tfrecords because reading csv is too slow for my needs