# How to use tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset with missing data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflow-datasets

I've been unable to get `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` to work with a CSV that contains missing data. As a toy example, suppose I have a single CSV file `example.csv` with the following contents:

```
date, value
D1,1017.1
D2, NA
```

When I run the following code, I receive the following error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 1 in record is not a valid float:  NA [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]`

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
            file_pattern=filenames,
            column_names=['date', 'value'],
            column_defaults=[tf.string, tf.float32],
            header=True,
            field_delim=',',
            na_value='NA'
        )
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```

Am I misusing the function? How am I supposed to specify that `NA` should be interpreted as a missing value? Replacing `NA` with a literal empty string results in the same problem:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 1 is required but missing in record! [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]`

My system's details:

- TensorFlow version (use command below): v1.12.0-0-ga6d8ffae09 1.12.0
- Python version: 3.6

Comment: I think this error is because you have specified column_defaults argument, which forces the default to be a float32 dtype only. Can you try without that?

Comment: I just tried the same on colab and it looks like it works.

Comment: Wow - nice catch! Two follow up questions. First, how did you discover that interaction? I just reread the documentation and that isn't clear to me at all. Second, if I remove `column_defaults`, then missing floating values are replaced by 0s, whereas if I replace the missing floating values in the CSV with `'NA'`, then `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` sets `dtype=object`. How do I keep the column type as `tf.float32` while maintaining the `NA`s?

Comment: For the first question, I looked up the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/readers.py#L434). In the source code, if you have not provided column defaults, it tries to infer the same and uses na_value as one of the arguments. So made a guess that could be the issue! Regarding your second follow up question, unfortunately, I am not able to find anything in the source code that suggests we can use float32 but also maintain NA's. I am not sure if this in an intended inconvenience!

Comment: From the documentation about column_defaults, the default values seem to be scalar or empty tensors and the source code does not seem to indicate anything different either depending on other arguments coming in to play.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823229/10111931) seems to be looking at a similar problem. the casting and converting seems to be probably the only useful alternative, but I think that in essence is also a lot of unnecessary work for no reason!

Comment: Thanks for all this :)

Comment: sure! Hope it helps somewhat!